# Set focus to UIElement (i.e. TextBox ) in XAML , using Silverlight 4?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, uielement

I have only seen code solutions to this problem. I am looking for a XAML based solution and I am quiet surprised you can't set focus on a UI element in XAML.

I found this old MSDN post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/09dc837d-4485-4966-b45b-266727bbb90c

that had the solution I sought ( this is WPF only I guess )

```
<Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=listBox1}">
```

Is setting focus to a TextBox/ListBox in *Silverlight 4* XAML not possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no, there is not a way in XAML to set the focus of an element.  You'll have to resort to something like you've referenced.  I think an attached behavior (similar to the `FocusManager`) would be the best route.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I haven't found a way to do this in XAML, so I'll have to resort to other means.

Answer (score 7):

There is always a way in XAML, if you try hard enough. :)  What you need is a `Trigger`, from the Blend SDK.

```
public class FocusTrigger : TargetedTriggerAction<Control>
{
   protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
   {
      if (Target == null)
         return;

      Target.Focus();
   }
}
```

Then to use it something like:

```
<Button Content="Move focus">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
      <local:FocusTrigger TargetName="TheTextBox"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
<TextBox x:Name="TheTextBox"/>
```

If you want to get REALLY fancy, you can [apply a condition to your trigger](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/09/14/blend-bits-8-trigger-fires-action.aspx) and do all sorts of crazy things in XAML.  I will say I am surprised this sort of thing isn't built in though.